# Как дату из списка конвертировать с помощью Datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Столкнулась со следующей проблемой.
Из БД возвращается дата в виде `datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 10, 00, 00)`
То есть возвращается не конвертированная дата, а именно строка `"datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 10, 00, 00)"`

через Python получилось выдернуть из неё дату и превратить в список с числами типа

```
date = [2019, 6, 10, 00, 00]
```

Как можно данный список преобразовать в формат `datetime.datetime(date)`?

P.S.  Проблемы с БД не в моей власти и пока их решить нет возможности, спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Нашла ещё один вариант.

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 10, 00, 00).isoformat()
print(dt)
# 2019-06-10T00:00
```

Comment: Практически тот же самый вариант в общем-то.

Comment: Возможно, но этот вариант освобождает от выдёргивания даты через regex, и преобразования в список. То есть именно в моём случае вместо 4-5 строк кода, получается всего одна

Answer (score 1):

Так как возвращаемое из БД значение является валидным выражением языка, парсинг строки можно передать средствам языка.

```
import ast
import datetime
from operator import attrgetter

value_from_db = "datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 10, 00, 00)"

expr, = ast.parse(value_from_db).body
dt_value = datetime.datetime(*map(attrgetter('n'), expr.value.args))

print(dt_value)  # 2019-06-10 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
import datetime

date = [2019, 6, 10, 00, 00]

dt = datetime.datetime(*date)
print(dt) # 2019-06-10 00:00:00
```

Comment: Ну тогда уж: `dt = datetime.datetime(*date)`

Comment: Спасибо, за уточнение, про распаковку списков я забыл :(